# Aligning text next to an image within a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[What I'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLYO2.jpg)

New to CSS+HTML and trying to practice my 'skills' which I have developed so far.

I've spent so many hours trying to get the text to align but it just will not.

[Here's what i've had achieved so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc8JV.png)

That in itself took ages just to figure out how to align the four cards like that.
I still cannot figure out how to align this text though.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="burger-layout">
    <div class="burger-item">
        <h2>HFC Classic</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with dill pickles,
            cos lettuce & egg mayo.</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="kj">2800Kj</li>
            <li class="price">$14.50</li>
            <li class="Details">More Details</li>
        </ul>
        <img src="hfc.png" alt="" class="burgerimg">

    </div>

    <div class="burger-item">
        <h2>HFC Hot</h2>

        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked
            in extra virgin olive oil with our Hawthorn
            Hot Sauce, jalapeños, slaw, shredded carrot, Spanish onion & egg mayo.</span>
        <ul class="burgerfooter">
            <li class="kj">2910Kj</li>
            <li class="price">$15.90</li>
            <li class="Details">More Details</li>
        </ul>
        <img src="hot.png" alt="" class="burgerimg">

    </div>

    <div class="burger-item">
        <h2>HFC Smokey</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with chipotle
            mayo, dill pickles, slaw & Spanish onion.</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="kj">2700Kj</li>
            <li class="price">$15.50</li>
            <li class="Details">More Details</li>
        </ul>
        <img src="smokey.png" alt="" class="burgerimg">

    </div>

    <div class="burger-item">
        <h2>HFC Blat</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with crispy bacon,
            avocado, cos lettuce, tomato & herbed mayo.</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="kj">2600Kj</li>
            <li class="price">$15.90</li>
            <li class="Details">More Details</li>
        </ul>
        <img src="blat.png" alt="" class="burgerimg">

    </div>



</div>
```

Here is my CSS so far: (note: I know the indentation is off here, its correct in my IDE)

```
body {
display: flex; 
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-width: 10vh;

}

.burger-layout{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
column-gap: 10px;
row-gap: 10px;
}
.burger-item {
border: 1px grey solid;
border-radius: 10px;
max-width: 537px;
max-height: 210px;




}

.burgerimg {
display: flex;
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
padding: 10px 10px;


}

.burger-description {

 }
```

Comment: Try using a table.

Comment: Please update your question tags and include css-grid instead of flexbox

Comment: There's a lot of work to be done here with flexbox to get this layout where you need it to be. To begin with, you need to set `display: flex` on .burger-item, then start nudging that to look like the original layout, and switch the position of the images and h2s in the layout, that will make this easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `image` and `info` into two different containers and use flex.

As you want to slice the layout into 2 parts. Let say `left` and `right`.

`Left` is the one that contains an image and as we need to give width and height and also some padding that's why you need to wrap it into a container. You can do this without wrapping it and then you've to use `margin` to give some space between the outer container and image.

Similarly `Right` is the one that contains information. And you want to slice the container into 2 parts.

> Flexbox works only in one direction either `horizontally` or `vertically`. All direct children of flexbox containers are flex-items. According to flex-direction, flex-items are placed accordingly. In you case image and other info should be side-by-side, so I wrap both in different container. If you don't wrap the all text container into one then they all come side by side or top to bottom as per your direction.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 10vh;
}

.burger-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.burger-item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 537px;
  max-height: 210px;
}

.image-container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

img.burgerimg {
  height: 100%;
}

.info-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.info-container ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.Details {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="burger-layout">
  <div class="burger-item">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" class="burgerimg">
    </div>
    <div class="info-container">
      <div>
        <h2>HFC Classic</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with dill pickles,
              cos lettuce & egg mayo.</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="kj">2800Kj</li>
        <li class="price">$14.50</li>
        <li class="Details">More Details</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="burger-item">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" class="burgerimg">
    </div>
    <div class="info-container">
      <div>
        <h2>HFC Classic</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with dill pickles,
              cos lettuce & egg mayo.</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="kj">2800Kj</li>
        <li class="price">$14.50</li>
        <li class="Details">More Details</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="burger-item">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" class="burgerimg">
    </div>
    <div class="info-container">
      <div>
        <h2>HFC Classic</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with dill pickles,
              cos lettuce & egg mayo.</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="kj">2800Kj</li>
        <li class="price">$14.50</li>
        <li class="Details">More Details</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="burger-item">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" class="burgerimg">
    </div>
    <div class="info-container">
      <div>
        <h2>HFC Classic</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with dill pickles,
              cos lettuce & egg mayo.</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="kj">2800Kj</li>
        <li class="price">$14.50</li>
        <li class="Details">More Details</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="burger-item">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" class="burgerimg">
    </div>
    <div class="info-container">
      <div>
        <h2>HFC Classic</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with dill pickles,
              cos lettuce & egg mayo.</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="kj">2800Kj</li>
        <li class="price">$14.50</li>
        <li class="Details">More Details</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="burger-item">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" class="burgerimg">
    </div>
    <div class="info-container">
      <div>
        <h2>HFC Classic</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with dill pickles,
        cos lettuce & egg mayo.</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="kj">2800Kj</li>
        <li class="price">$14.50</li>
        <li class="Details">More Details</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. I was curious if you could quickly explain why wrapping the img in a different container works?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap all your content except img in separate div
and you need to add flex to your  ".burger-item "   , and you need to change some styles for your  ".burgerimg "

But i suggest you change something , and experiment on your own

Working code :

```
   <div class="burger-layout">
    <div class="burger-item">
            <div class="wraper">   <!-- new div that wraps all except img -->
        <h2>HFC Classic</h2>
        <span class="burger-description">RSPCA Approved chicken, cooked in extra virgin olive oil with dill pickles,
            cos lettuce & egg mayo.</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="kj">2800Kj</li>
            <li class="price">$14.50</li>
            <li class="Details">More Details</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  <!-- end of ned div -->

        <img src="./tommaso-teloni-o9E5dEiOw_o-unsplash.jpg" alt=""    class="burgerimg">
    </div>


  body {
display: flex; 
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-width: 10vh;

}

.burger-layout{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
column-gap: 10px;
row-gap: 10px;
}

.burger-item {
border: 1px grey solid;
border-radius: 10px;
max-width: 537px;
max-height: 210px;

flex-direction: row-reverse;   /* new */  

display: flex;  /* new */   
align-items: center;  /* new */
justify-content: space-around;  /* new */

}


.burgerimg {
display: flex;
display: inline-block;
max-width: 300px;  /* new */
max-height: 300px; /* new */
padding: 10px 10px;

width: 40%;  /* new */
height: 100%;  /* new */ 

}
```